# У меня вискакиваєт ошибка syntaх error помогите пожалуста ю

Tags: python, discord-api

Вот код

````
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

client = discord.Client()


import random
Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@Bot.event 
async def on_ready():
 print ('I\'m' + " " + 'connect.')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user :
        return


@Bot.command()
async def buy(ctx):
      random1 = random.randrange(1,8)
      if random1 == 1:
       await ctx.send('Мені так подобається коли ти пяний(а) .')
      elif random1 == 2:
       await ctx.send('Хочеш мокачіно з молоком .Тримай .')
      elif random1 == 3:
       await ctx.send('В мене обід .Навіть якщо зараз ніч мені всерівно.')
      elif random1 == 4:
       await ctx.send('А тобі не забагато ну ок тримай пиріжок .')
      elif random1 == 5:
       await ctx.send('Discord це бар ,а я бармен .')
      elif random1 == 6:
       await ctx.send('Капучіно з молоком і льодом це краще що в мене є !!!')
      elif random1 == 7:
       await ctx.send('Ти вже ледь стоїш на ногах ,але через те що цей бар тільки на тобі й тримається тому тримай бублик:)')
      await ctx.message.delete()

@Bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
       await Bot.send('Hello {}'.format(ctx.message.author)




Bot.run('тут токен')```
Ошибка
  File "Discord-Bot-Test-1.py", line 48
    Bot.run('тут токен')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Press any key to continue . . .


Токен я забрал сечас специально
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке

```
await Bot.send('Hello {}'.format(ctx.message.author)
```

нет закрывающей скобки.

Comment: Спасибо ви мне очень помогли